# Aussprache: "aus halb-, halber-, halben-Liter-Gläsern trinken"

Tags: pronunciation, numbers

Ich möchte *1/2* im folgenden Satz aussprechen. Wie wird *1/2* in diesem Fall korrekt ausgesprochen?

> Man trinkt das Münchener aus 1/2-Liter-Gläsern.

Comment: Kein Münchner trinkt Bier aus irgendwelchen Gläsern! Dafür gibt es Krüge!

Comment: Einspruch! Weißbier- oder Hellesgläser, wenn sie bloß eine Halbe enthalten, sind Gläser und keine Krüge!

Answer (score 7):

Man sagt üblicherweise: "Man trinkt das Münchener aus Halb-Liter-Gläsern.".

Wenn man sagt "Man trinkt aus einem Halben-Liter-Glas" oder "Man trinkt aus Halben-Liter-Gläsern" hört sich das in dem Zusammenhang nicht falsch an für mich als Muttersprachler, jedoch würde ich die obige Variante bevorzugen, da man das auf die Art dann nicht mit "einem halben Liter-Glas" verwechseln kann.

"Aus einem Halber-Liter-Glas trinken" oder "Aus Halber-Liter-Gläsern trinken" klingt für mich beides nicht korrekt.

Comment: Fast korrekt. Nur würde man üblicherweise nicht von einem *Münchner* sprechen, diese Brauerei ist mir nicht bekannt. Man kann natürlich das Paulaner, das Hacker, das Spaten, das Erdinger etc. aus Halblitergläsern trinken ;)

Comment: Stimmt :), aber die Frage so gestellt ist, habe ich das mal übernommen.

Comment: Muenchener ist vor allem in Bayern beliebt :)

Answer (score 1):

Die einzig natürlichen Varianten für mich sind:

> Man trinkt das Bier aus einem Nullkommafünf-Liter-Glas.
>   Man trinkt das Bier aus einem Null-Fünfer-Glas.

Wohlgemerkt komme ich nicht aus München oder Umgebung und bei uns gibt es recht selten das Bier in Gläser mit einem Fassungsvermögen von 0,5 Liter. Meistens sind es 0,2 oder 0,3 Liter. Und da spricht man nicht von 1/5 oder 1/3 Liter.
Ausnahme ist das Weizenglas, welches aber als "Weizenglas" bezeichnet wird. Oder — in seltenen Fällen — eben als 0,5-Liter-Glas.

Jegliche Variante mit "Halb-Liter" klingt in meinen Ohren äußerst merkwürdig. Verstehen würde ich es natürlich trotzdem.

Comment: In meinem Umfeld würde man das Komma und den Liter beim Sprechen weg lassen, also z.B. ein "Null-fünfer" bestellen.

Comment: @Marzipanherz Stimmt, das gibt's auch noch. Ich werde das noch ergänzend anführen.

Comment: Bier aus einem 0,2 oder 0,3 Liter Glas zu trinken ist eine Schande. Das sind keine Biergläser ;-)